# ArcGIS Javascript API Button click not working

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I have added layers into the page and trying to get layer feature attributes on button click using ARCGIS Javascript API. The mapView is loading corretly with Legends and all details in it. But the tool for fetching layer attributes on button click not working. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples
    on iOS devices-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Map with legend</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/esri/css/esri.css">

  <style>
    html, body {
      height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
#search{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 20px;
        left: 74px;
      }
#execute{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 20px;
        left: 74px;
      }
    #rightPane {
      width: 20%;
    }

    #legendPane {
      border: solid #97DCF2 1px;
    }
  </style>
 <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/"></script>
  <script>
    var map;
    require([
      "esri/map","esri/layers/FeatureLayer","esri/dijit/Legend",
      "dojo/_base/array","dojo/parser",
      "dijit/layout/BorderContainer","dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
      "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer","esri/tasks/query", 
            "esri/tasks/QueryTask","dojo/dom","dojo/on","dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
      Map, FeatureLayer, Legend,
      arrayUtils, parser,
            Query,QueryTask,dom,on
    ) {
      parser.parse();

      map = new Map("map", {
        basemap:"topo",
        center: [78.629, 18.092],
        zoom: 5
      });

            var offices = new FeatureLayer("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/FrimData/MapServer/0", {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        outFields:["*"]
      });
            var route = new FeatureLayer("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/FrimData/MapServer/1", {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        outFields:["*"]
      });
             var depth = new FeatureLayer("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/FrimData/MapServer/2", {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        outFields:["*"]
      });
              var economicZone = new FeatureLayer("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/FrimData/MapServer/3", {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        outFields:["*"]
      });
       var boundary = new FeatureLayer("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/FrimData/MapServer/4", {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        outFields:["*"]
      });
      //add the legend
      map.on("layers-add-result", function (evt) {
        var layerInfo = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function (layer, index) {
          return {layer:layer.layer, title:layer.layer.name};
        });
        if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
          var legendDijit = new Legend({
            map: map,
            layerInfos: layerInfo
          }, "legendDiv");
          legendDijit.startup();
        }
      });    

      map.addLayers([route,depth,economicZone,boundary,offices]);

            var queryTask = new QueryTask("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/FrimData/MapServer/0");

        var query = new Query();
        query.returnGeometry = false;

                query.outFields = [
          "Name", "OBJECTID"
        ];


            on(dom.byId("execute"), "click", executes); 

            function executes () {
        alert("df");
          query.text = dom.byId("stateName").value;
          queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
        }

        function showResults(results){
            var resultItems = [];
            var resultCount = results.features.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
                var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
                for (var attr in featureAttributes) {
                    alert(featureAttributes[attr]);
                    resultItems.push("<b>" + attr + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[attr] + "<br>");
                }
                resultItems.push("<br>");
            }
        }

    });

  </script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<![endif]-->
<div id="content"
     data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
     data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:true"
     style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">

 <div id="rightPane"
       data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
       data-dojo-props="region:'right'">

    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane"
           data-dojo-props="title:'Legend', selected:true">
        <div id="legendDiv"></div>
      </div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
           data-dojo-props="title:'Pane 2'">
        This pane could contain tools or additional content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map"
       data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
       data-dojo-props="region:'center'"
       style="overflow:hidden;">
  </div>
    <div id="search"></div>
     <input type="text" id="stateName" value="1">
    <input id="execute" type="button" value="Get Details">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

From the step button click `on(dom.byId("execute"), "click", executes);` It is not working. I refered this example `https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/query_nomap.html`I am new to this. Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a mismatch in the AMD modules you require and modules you actually reference for the function. Hope that helps

```
    var map;
require([
  "esri/map",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/dijit/Legend",
  "dojo/_base/array",
  "dojo/parser",
  "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
  "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
  "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer",
  "esri/tasks/query", 
  "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/on","dojo/domReady!"
], function(
  Map, FeatureLayer, Legend, arrayUtils, parser, BorderContainer, ContentPane, AccordionContainer, Query, QueryTask, dom, on
) {
  parser.parse();

  map = new Map("map", {
    basemap:"topo",
    center: [78.629, 18.092],
    zoom: 5
  });


    on(dom.byId("execute"), "click", function() {
        console.info("got it");
        alert("df");                
    });          
});
```